# How can I conditionally trigger an Azure pipeline based on the results of another Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I've got two Azure pipelines, P0 and P1. Currently, P1 is triggered to run when P0 completes as a build completion trigger.

[image]

If P0 fails, I do not want to trigger P1. There doesn't appear to be a way to add a condition to only trigger builds based on the successful completion of a previous build. We have to start P1 and cancel it based on a condition.

The only way I see to do this is via either:

1. Setting an environment variable via a build script in P0, `Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildContinue;]$buildContinue")`, and reading that variable via a script in P1 via a build task variable `$(BuildContinue)`.
2. Setting a semaphore file as a build artifact in P0 and then downloading and reading that file in P1.

Both options require running the build. Is there a better way to conditionally run an Azure pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't support conditional build completion triggers.

In the short term, your good options are:

- Pass along a flag in some form, as you suggested. Requires running the P1 build, but I don't see what harm that causes (you might have some reason why it's not suitable that I don't see).
- Unify the two pipelines into a single, multi-job pipeline. You probably have good reasons why you aren't doing that today, but you could block the P1 job from ever running by setting a condition.
- Instead of defining a P1 trigger that watches P0, have a step on P0 which uses the REST API to queue a run. This just barely qualifies as a "good" option – it meets the letter of your requirements but isn't very elegant.